# Difference between angular.element().scope().$root and angular.element().injector().get('$rootScope')

Tags: angularjs, rootscope

I am finding it very difficult to find the root cause of a particular issue in my code. The source code is [here](http://mvpspl619.github.io/ng-stats/)

I want to access `$rootScope`, but one of the way is failing.

**Route 1:**

Get the first element in DOM with `ng-scope` class and do a `angular.element(elem).scope().$root` to get the root.

**Route 2:**

Get the first element in DOM with `ng-scope` class and get the injector on the element by `angular.element(elem).injector()` and by doing a `injector().get('$rootScope')` I can get the `$rootScope`.

In **Route 1** when my code does, `angular.element(document.querySelector('.ng-scope')).scope()` I get undefined because `scope` is not available on this element. I tried to get the `angular.element(elem).data()`, but I get an empty object.

Does this mean that angular has not yet run through this element ? If yes, why do I see an `ng-scope` class already being applied if angular has not yet gone through this element ?

What is the difference between accessing `$rootScope` through `injector().get('$rootScope')` and through `scope().$root` ? Why does my **Route 1** fail ?

**Route 1:**

[image]

**Route 2:**

[image]